# osx app optimal font type

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, fonts

i searching for an optimal font for my OS X app.
at the moment i use "Avenir Next", but i think that dies font is not optimize for every situation or i make an mistake.

for example:
i have this textfield, where I set the font of Avernir Next Regular and it loos like this:

[image]

the placeholder label is not vertical center.
this issue I have with all textfields, too.

is this my fault or should i use another font (which font) ?

[image]

Comment: select your textfield ,go to editor , click on size to fit content

Comment: where is this option? i added a new picture in post 1

Comment: select your text field in story board then at the top most bar of your xcode you will find editor

Comment: which xcode u are using?

Comment: it is version 8.3.3

Comment: Size to Fit Content is in the Editor menu, Command-=. I think the default font is least likely to give you problems because everything is tested using the default font. Another font should work fine though.

Comment: if i select the textfield and go to Editor menu, the size to fit content is disabled